# How to watch server messages while running heroku Django app on localhost

Tags: python, django, heroku

We can see all printed messages in command line while running our Django apps on localhost.

But how to see when we run heroku app locally.

I used below command to run my app:

```
foreman start web
```

I have printed so many messages inside views.py file like below:

```
class web_index(View):
    def get(self, request):
        print "inside get method"
        return render(request, 'home.html', locals())

    def post(self, request):
        print "inside post method"
        return render(request, 'home.html', locals())
```

So this must print two messages called inside get method when it get method is called and same for post method.

In real implementation my code is much bigger and I used print for showing errors.
But i really don't know where to look for those all printed messages.?
Please help.
I'm new to Heroku and Django. Don't degrade question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I searched on google so much and get below solution.

Just create a .env extension file.

put that file next to your Procfile, and add below environment variable to the first line

```
PYTHONUNBUFFERED=true
```

That’s it, the next time I will run my project with

```
 foreman start web
```

I will see all the output.

This works for me. Hope it will work for others.